# How to remove the zeros on the left using Php

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
0001 => 1

0010 => 10

0100 => 100
```

I want to remove the zero on the left

Any suggestions?

Needs to be in PHP

Comment: Are you referring to three strings or an array?

Comment: Nguyen, have you found suitable solution in any of those five answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept  the solution that is best for you to close the question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string

You Can Use The code Below For a String or an Array:

```
echo ltrim("001221", '0');

$array = array("00051", "205400", "01022", "0005","000000");

foreach($array as $item) {
  $new_item = ltrim($item, '0');
  echo $new_item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ltrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ltrim method in PHP:

$string = ltrim($string, '0');

Comment: No @AlivetoDie . I t won't work like that please check the below code executed fine <?php

$str="0012200";

$str=ltrim($str, '0');

echo $str;exit();

?>

Answer (score 0):

**Type Casting**

Convert the string number to integer using `(int)`, ie use *Type Casting*  is write desired type in parentheses before the variable:

```
<?php
echo (int)"00001" . PHP_EOL; // output is 1
echo (int)"00010" . PHP_EOL; // output is 10
echo (int)"00100" . PHP_EOL; // output is 100
echo (int)"01000" . PHP_EOL; // output is 1000

// usage with variable
$string = "00010";  // number as a string
$integer = (int)$string; // type casted to integer
var_dump($integer);  // output is (int)10
```

**[Live Demo](https://eval.in/939203)**

[PHP Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

The casts allowed are:

> `(int)`, `(integer)` - cast to integer
>     `(bool)`, `(boolean)` - cast to boolean
>     `(float)`, `(double)`, `(real)` - cast to float
>      `(string)` - cast to string
>      `(array)` - cast to array
>      `(object)` - cast to object
>      `(unset)` - cast to NULL